# The requested image's platform does not match the detected host platform and no specific platform was requested

Tags: docker, docker-compose

as I was trying to Build a container, I faced this issue and had to try a lot of stuff to find the problem. This happens if I try to build a Linux-based container on windows.

```
[Warning] The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (windows/amd64) and no specific platform was requested
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying everything on the Internet I remembered that I had switched to windows containers to troubleshoot something.

**Just switch Windows Containers back to Linux Containers and it should work (It worked for me)**

Now if you have the same issue but on **starting** a container, then go ahead and **add the option `--platform=linux/amd64`** or whatever suits you.

Comment: Could you please describe where to add this option?